# How to set text to RadioButton which is inside of a RadioGroup programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have a `RadioGroup` inside of which I have some `RadioButton`s.

I want to set some text on the `RadioButton`s programmatically. I used following code for that using that I'm unable to access the `RadioButton`s inside of the `RadioGroup` using Java.

How can I set the text on a `RadioButton` inside a `RadioGroup`?

XML Layout:

```
<RadioGroup android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/QueGroup1">

    <RadioButton android:checked="false"
        android:button="@drawable/green"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:id="@+id/rbtnYes"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RadioButton android:checked="false"
        android:button="@drawable/red"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/rbtnNo"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RadioButton android:checked="false"
        android:button="@drawable/red"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Dont Know"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rbtnDontKnow"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Java code:

```
private void fnRadioTextSet(String strval) {
    rbtnYes = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnYes);
    rbtnNo = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnNo);
    rbtnDontKnow = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbtnDontKnow);
    RadioGroup rbtnGrp = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.QueGroup1);
    String[] strArrtext = strval.split(",");
    for (int intcount = 0; intcount < strArrtext.length; intcount++) {
        rbtnGrp.getChildAt(intcount).settext("test");
    }

    //int i = rbtnGrp.getChildCount();
    //Toast.makeText(getApplication(), rbtnGrp.getChildCount(),
    //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /*String[] strtext = strval.split(",");
    if (strtext.length > 0) {

    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private void fnRadioTextSet(String strval) {
    RadioGroup rbtnGrp = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.QueGroup1);
    String[] strArrtext = strval.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < rbtnGrp.getChildCount(); i++) {
        ((RadioButton) rbtnGrp.getChildAt(i)).setText(strArrtext[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello!
I did the same, but the text is slide under the radiobutton and I can't see the being of it. Add padding or drawablePadding isn't help to me. Any idea? thx

Answer (score 2):

Don't need the loop

```
rbtnYes.settext("sdklfhjsdf");
rbtnNo.settext("test");
rbtnDontKnow.settext("test");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to set radio button text value using radio group object can it possible to do that?