# how to map value of HashMap onto RadioButtons

Tags: java, android, hashmap, radio-button

I m new in Android, and try to set Text onto RadioButons. i m using Hashmap method to get Values from list String (HashMap). i m able to display the value in Log view but not able to get Text onto RadioButtons

Please check Code and suggest Solutions

```html
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);

final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   key = entry.getKey();
   values = entry.getValue() != null;
   System.out.println("Key = " + key);
   System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");
   RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
   radioButtonView.setFreezesText(values);
   radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
                 
   }
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: check this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426317/how-to-set-text-to-radiobutton-which-is-inside-of-a-radiogroup-programmatically . it may help you

Comment: This tutorial will help http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/Addingaradiobuttonprogrammatically.htm

Comment: i m checking both links thanks @Swarna

Comment: i m checking link  @Ichigo Kurosaki

Comment: @Swarna i m able to make RadioButtons text in Previous project , but now  requirement is HashMap , i m able to get the values into log but not on RadioButtons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might help you, use this snipet of code

```
final   Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>(); 
ht.put("player 1", "sachin"); 
ht.put("player 2", "sehwag"); 
ht.put("player 3", "dhoni"); 
final Enumeration<String> values = ht.keys(); 

while (values.hasMoreElements()) { 
     String str = (String) values.nextElement(); 
     System.out.println(str + ":" + ht.get(str));

     RadioButton radioButtonView = new RadioButton(this);
     radioButtonView.setText(ht.get(str));
     selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
     radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView, p);
}
```